# Terminating ibuffer incremental search

Tags: search, ibuffer

When I terminate a Multi I-search, Emacs takes me back to the original buffer rather than the result I'm looking at.

I've tried terminating the search with RET, escape, arrow keys, and none of these have worked. What should I be doing instead?

To reproduce:

1. Start Emacs with `emacs -Q`
2. Open several buffers.
3. `M-x ibuffer`
4. Mark several buffers with `m`
5. Start Multi I-search with `M-s a C-s`
6. Search for something and press `C-s` until you're in at least the second buffer.
7. `RET` returns you to the original buffer!

Comment: Arrow keys work for me. Have you tried other key sequences for movement (`C-f`, `C-b`, etc.)?

Comment: Those don't work either.

Comment: Works for me. What version of Emacs are you running? Can you reproduce the problem if you run `emacs -q`? If you run `emacs -Q`? If `emacs -q` doesn't reproduce the problem, then the problem is in your init file, and you'll need to post it, or preferably the part of it that causes the problem, to get help.

Comment: The problem is reproduced in `emacs -q` but `emacs -Q` works properly. What might that mean?

Comment: After playing around further, I see that I receive the intended behavior only **sometimes** using `emacs -Q`. Other times I receive my initial problem. I am running emacs 24.3.1.

Comment: Interesting, I can reproduce this. I end up in a recursive edit in the first buffer that was searched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The search returns to the original buffer when a recursive edit is used for modal searching. But multi-file search doesn't support modal isearch. This problem is fixed in Emacs 24.4 (scheduled to be released next week as I write).

Comment: "the next emacs version will be released the next week" Are you sure of that? Anyway, you should include absolute values ("as of version ...", "the problem is fixed in version ... that will be released on ..."), that will make the question and answer more useful to a future reader.

Comment: [Original Announcement](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2014-10/msg00376.html)